# PowerShell and Robocopy - Robocopy not initiating.

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PS command that I can manually run in PS ISE. Everything works except for RoboCopy. If I take the Log argument out, it works fine. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Running Windows 10.

```
Get-ChildItem * -Include *.txt -Recurse | Remove-Item -verbose

Start-Process "RoboCopy.exe" -argumentlist "`"C:\SSDT`" `"C:\SSDT2`" /COPY:DAT /E /Z /FFT /MT:20 /R:2 /W:3 /XO /XF *.tmp /XF desktop.ini /XF Default.rdp /LOG:C:\Backup\%DATE:/=-%-RoboCopy.txt /V /TEE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running in PowerShell, cmd.exe style variables do not work.

Thus `%DATE:/=-%-` will actually be that string which contains invalid characters. You could use the `Get-Date` cmdlet to generate the same format of date.

```
Get-Date -Format 'ddd MM-dd-yyyy'
```

Then using a subexpression `$()` you could insert that into your command.

```
Start-Process "RoboCopy.exe" -argumentlist "`"C:\SSDT`" `"C:\SSDT2`" /COPY:DAT /E /Z /FFT /MT:20 /R:2 /W:3 /XO /XF *.tmp /XF desktop.ini /XF Default.rdp /LOG:C:\Backup\$(Get-Date -Format 'ddd MM-dd-yyyy')-RoboCopy.txt /V /TEE"
```

Comment: Thank you- I'm new to PS and am trying to convert some simple scripts to learn. That worked for me.

Comment: FYI `Start-Process` is not necessary.